# How to modify array's element while iterating

Tags: ruby

I have an array in Ruby `["eat", "pie"]` and I would like to iterate this array and while I am iterating append the chars `"ay"` at the end of every element of the array...how is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have to / want to modify the elements _while iterating_ the array?

Comment: Not my preference, but `["eat", "pie"].product(["ay"]).map(&:join) #=> ["eatay", "pieay"]` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
array = ["eat","pie"]
p array.map { |element| "#{element}ay" }
# => ["eatay", "pieay"]
```

It gives you a new array with the modification you've done, your "original" array remains as before:

```
p array.map { |element| "#{element}ay" } # ["eatay", "pieay"]
p array # ["eat", "pie"]
```

For more info. see [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [map!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21).

Comment: great! and if I want this (while iterating, if the element starts with "e" add "ay", while if it starts with "p" add "ya") how this is possible?

Comment: That's a different question. [Look around](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pig+latin+ruby), you're not the first one asking that.

Comment: @naufragio you would need a [conditional](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html), e.g. `if element.start_with?('e') ...`

Answer (score 2):

Array#collect applies the given block of code on all the items of an array and returns the new array.

```
array = ["eat","pie"]
array.collect { |element| "#{element}ay" }
```